# Magento 2 Checkout page customer address attribute save Dropdown value

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, attributes, customer

I have created one module that has created Customer Attribute called Title:

For that i have created layout processor **Vendor/Modulename/Plugin/Checkout/Model/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php**

```
      class LayoutProcessor
 {
/**
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
 * @param array $jsLayout
 * @return array
 */
public function afterProcess(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
    array  $jsLayout
) {
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
    ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['delivery_date'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/date',
            'options' => [],
            'id' => 'delivery-date'
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.delivery_date',
        'label' => 'Delivery Date',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'visible' => true,
        'validation' => [],
        'sortOrder' => 250,
        'id' => 'delivery-date'
    ];

    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
    ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['cutitle'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
            'id' => 'drop-down',
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.cutitle',
        'label' => 'Drop Down',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'visible' => true,
        'validation' => [],
        'sortOrder' => 251,
        'id' => 'cutitle',
        'options' => [
            [
                'value' => '',
                'label' => 'Please Select',
            ],
            [
                'value' => 'mrs',
                'label' => 'Mrs.',
            ],
            [
                'value' => 'mr',
                'label' => 'Mr.',
            ]

        ]
    ];

     return $jsLayout;
   }
```

**Plugin: di.xml**

```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin name="dipen_add_custom_field" type="Vendor\Modulename\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
   </type>



   </config>
```

I want to save dropdown attribute value and it should show in admin order. What's missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for your question, it is a very useful question for us all willing to modify Magento 2 checkout.
I have changed the id "cutitle" from your field to "prefix" and that fixes the issue or I believe it does:
- the title value of your drop down is saved correctly and the field **name prefix** has this data.
- the data does not appear in the address rendering but I understand you are trying to saved this prefix first and foremost?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  I have added dropdown on checkout page using layout processor but how can i save it?  It should show in order as well.  Is there anyway i can save it once order place?  Do i need to develop any method to show it in admin or it will do automatically?

Comment: If your dropdown is the Customer Title that appears in your code snippet, I can see it, I have succeeded to save the customer title from your dropdown against the order. Not sure whether this means applying my answer does not work for you?